# Excluding strings from list of strings that contain substrings from separate list of substrings

Tags: dart

I am trying to exclude elements from a list of strings that contain any element from a separate list of strings to produce a third list of remaining strings from the first list.

```
var original_list = ['cigar', 'rebut', 'focal', 'blush', 'naval', 'bench'];
var exclusion_list = ['e', 'f'];
var result_list = [];
```

I'm still getting familiar with Dart syntax. In Python, I would have done something similar to:

```
for item in original_list:
    if not any(letter in original_list for letter in exclusion_list):
        result_list.append(item)
```

I've been going round and round in dartpad trying to come up with an elegant solution but I keep coming back to some ugly nested for loops.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you pleaes ask an actual question?

Comment: Are you saying that I should have stated, I would like advice implementing this particular list comprehension in dart?

Comment: Ask yourself what your question is. Once you know what your question is, put it in your question post. If you need guidance, [ask] is a great resource :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brutes-force implementation would be:

```dart
List<String> source = ...;
List<String> disallowedSubstrings = ...;
// ...
var result = <String>[];
outer:
for (var value in source) {
  for (var exception in disallowedSubstrings) {
    if (value.contains(exception)) {
      continue outer;
    }
  }
  result.add(value);
}
```

That's basically what you have, but using a label to continue the outer loop, instead of a flag to avoid doing more work inside it.

The inner loop can be replaced using `any`, becoming:

```dart
if (exception.any(value.contains)) {
  continue outer;
}
result.add(value);
```

It uses the [`Iterable.any`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/Iterable/any.html) method to check something for every element of `disallowedSubstrings`, and a method tear-off to do pass in a function which effectively does `(x) => value.contains(x)`.

But then we have an `if`, and might as well write it to guard the rest of the loop body, instead of continuing:

```dart
  if (!disallowedSubstrings.any(value.contains)) {
    result.add(value);
  }
```

That leaves us with a `for` and an `if` doing an `add`, which we can turn into a list literal:

```dart
var result = [for (var value in source) 
  if (!disallowedSubstrings.any(value.contains)) value
];
```

That's much closer to the Python version.

Alternatively, if not using a list literal, it can also be written as:

```dart
var result = source.where((value) => 
    !disallowedSubstrings.any(value.contains)
).toList();
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've landed on this

```
      var list1 = ['cigar', 'rebut', 'focal', 'blush', 'naval', 'bench'];
      var list2 = ['e', 'f'];
      var remaining = [];
      int flag;
      
      for(int i = 0;i < list1.length;i++) {
        flag = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < list2.length;j++) {
          if(list1[i].contains(list2[j])) {
            flag = 1;
            continue;
          }
        }
        if(flag==0) {
          remaining.add(list1[i]);
        }
      }
```

Not the most elegant but it will "filter" out the strings in list1 that contain the characters in list2.

Comment: You have not added the required response, and have actually stated the problem in code. The question was how to avoid the "ugly loops"...